# Decimal counter in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, counter

I would like to implement a decimal counter that will count from 0 to 9999 on the LED display on a Digilent BASYS2 board. Can somebody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: With code, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your question asks for a complete and ready example, which is a less-than-ideal fit for a Q&A format like Stack Exchange. Could you show what you have tried and where exactly you got stuck? It's not that no one wants to help, it's just that you'll hardly get the complete walk-through of the entire problem, as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

You need a counter linked to a bcd to 7 segment decoder. I learnt my VHDL from a book called '[Free Range VHDL](http://www.freerangefactory.org/site/pmwiki.php/Main/Books)'.  The book isn't perfect but it is downloadable as a PDF from the [free range factory](http://www.freerangefactory.org/) website. More importantly for you, it has examples of counters and decoders that may help you a lot.

Comment: Have you got any links to said book or website?

Comment: Sure. I was typing the above on an ebook reader so wasn't too keen on URLs. I'll change my post.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend an excellent tutorial written by [Mike Field](http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) called ["Introducing the Spartan 3E FPGA and VHDL"](https://github.com/hamsternz/IntroToSpartanFPGABook/blob/master/IntroToSpartanFPGABook.pdf?raw=true) because:

- It specifically refers to the Basys2 board you mentioned
- It is only 120 pages long and is well written
- It shows the way but doesn't write all the code for you (so you will learn better)
- It has a chapter on displaying decimal on 7-segment displays
- I've used it with my Digilent Nexys3 board without too much fuss.

Comment: +1 for the link. Without guidance it can be a bit overwhelming initially to go from VHDL to synthesis using the Xilinx toolset. The tutorial you link to seems to cover this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

try and use google a little bit more. You already have all the key words that you need to get a lot of good answers on google. [VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL)

If you want a good advise, take a pencil, a sheet and draw your circuit using flip-flop and other gates. You will learn a lot! If you know how your design works, writing VHDL/Verilog will be easy. So first draw your circuit. Also, maybe learn on RTL design. Peter Ashenden wrote a lot of books that can help you. [RTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level)